# Конфигурация resource handlers для Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, config

Как сделать то же самое, что я указал в примере с кодом, используя Spring Boot (+Security)?
Реализация WebMvcConfigurer интерфейса сбрасывает многие настройки, которые были выполнены boot'ом автоматически. Например, перестает работать настройка в application.properties "spring.mvc.hiddenmethod.filter.enabled=true". Вопрос в том, как настроить связку нескольких пар ResourceHandler:ResourceLocation, не конфигурируя при этом лишнее.
Или нужно совсем не так это делать, направьте в нужную сторону, пожалуйста.

```java
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebMvc
    public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
        @Override
        public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
            registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**")
                    .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/assets/css/");
            registry.addResourceHandler("/images/**")
                    .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/assets/images/");
            registry.addResourceHandler("/js/**")
                    .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/assets/js/");
            registry.addResourceHandler("/person-storage/**")
                    .addResourceLocations("classpath:/storage/person-images/");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У Spring Boot есть класс `WebMvcAutoConfiguration` который настраивает все эти ваши MVC и именно он создаёт бин `OrderedHiddenHttpMethodFilter` если `spring.mvc.hiddenmethod.filter.enabled` установлен в`true`. Добавив аннотацию `@EnableWebMvc` на класс конфигурации вы этот класс отключили и теперь должны руками сделать всё что делал класс `WebMvcAutoConfiguration`.

Просто уберите `@EnableWebMvc`

Comment: Спасибо за лаконичный ответ! Не додумался отключить эту аннотацию, думал, без неё конфигурация не будет работать.

Comment: Mvc конфигурация всё равно переопределяет методы, связанные с фильтром. Boot накидывает поверх конфигурацию, используя properties? Не совсем понятно, как эта магия происходит.

Comment: @Виктор не понял вопроса, переформулируйте, пожалуйста

Comment: [Nick](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/216863/nick), WebMvcAutoConfiguration создает бины, я добавляю свой @Configuration класс MvcConfig, реализующий интерфейс WebMvcConfigurer. У WebMvcConfigurer, как я понимаю, есть свои дефолтные реализации методов, один из них я переопределяю (addResourceHandlers). Сейчас всё работает так, как мне нужно, но я не понимаю, почему дефолтные реализации из WebMvcConfigurer не портят/не пересекаются с аналогичными из WebMvcAutoConfiguration.

Comment: @Виктор `WebMvcConfigurer` интерфейс, в нём нет реализаций. А не портится ничего потому что есть класс `DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration` (который импортируется аннотацией `EnableWebMvc`) который проходит циклом по всем кто реализует `WebMvcConfigurer`. Не знаю в какой IDE вы пишете код, но в Intellij IDEA можно побродить по исходному коду и посмотреть что там проиcходит

Comment: Спасибо, вы мне помогли